# Why is update_all updating way more records than it should even have access to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method

```
    def change_status_to_active(questions)
        puts "MARKING ACTIVE1: #{questions.pluck(:id).to_s}"
        originalCount = questions.count
        before = Question.where(status: QUESTION_STATUS_ACTIVE).count
        questions.update_all(status: QUESTION_STATUS_ACTIVE)
        after = Question.where(status: QUESTION_STATUS_ACTIVE).count
        puts "Active Orig: #{originalCount.to_s} Before: #{before.to_s} After: #{after.to_s}"
    end
```

Yet here is the output I'm getting...

```
Active Orig: 26 Before: 0 After: 122
```

How can this be?

questions.count = 26

Yet `questions.update_all(status: QUESTION_STATUS_ACTIVE)` is changing 122 records.

Answer (score 1):

`questions` is just a param to the `change_status_to_active` method and in your case, it has 26 records.

`before` count is 0 because none of your `Question` record is active yet.

Then, when you call:

```
questions.update_all(status: QUESTION_STATUS_ACTIVE)
```

this will update all the `Question` records in the database and set the `status` to active which you can see the `after` count is 126.

So, this looks perfectly alright.

Your `questions.count` is just the count of the questions in the local variable passed as an argument to the `change_status_to_active` method.

If you were to get the count of all the `questions` records, you would have to call:

`Question.count` NOT `questions.count`.

Comment: @Rakibul I don't want it to update all 122 records. I'm passing in a filtered var questions which has 26 records in it. I only want to update these 26. Yet when I call update_all on the variable, it updates 122. Why?

Comment: yes, this actually should only update the 26 records. I tested to verify myself. Can you see the corresponding SQL? Can you try the same this in rails console and see the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

What would be the result if you say Question.count and not questions.count ? Maybe you need a where condition in your update_all something like

Question.update_all("status='#{QUESTION_STATUS_ACTIVE}'",  ["field1 = ?", value1])

Comment: Question.all is 122. There are 122 records in the DB. In a different function not pictured here, I select a certain subset of question records that need to be marked as `active`. I pass them in via the questions variable. As you can see `questions.count=26` YET `questions.update_all(status: "A")` is affecting 122 records. How does that make any sense?

Comment: So looks like it called the entire table that's why you need the where statement part so that you can filter it.